Protection circuit for inverter or generator during blackouts
During blackouts in Ukraine it's a common practice to turn incoming AC voltage switch off and power all in-house power AC lines with an inverter or a gas/diesel generator.
Can someone share a protection circuit to avoid the damage of equipment if incoming power switch is on and power is back while an inverter or generator is connected?
As for me, triac can be used for this purpose, but I lack knowledge to design this circut by myself. I don't plan to power high-current appliances, just something like LED light bulbs, TV and PC.

You probably will trip the breakers of your generator the moment you switch it on if you don't disconnect from the utility line first because the generator would have to try to power at least your whole neighborhood electricity isn't a one way road).
